# Highlighting of compositor nodes?

Tags: interface, compositing-nodes

How to use it? Checkbox in compositor's *N-key panel* is enabled, but I see no difference in behaviour.

My PC is Win7 64 bit, 4gb RAM, card ATI HD4670 500mb.

Anyway, assuming it is working, what information can I get from it? Collateral indication of nodes' memory consumption? For example, nodes which will be firstly highlighted are less memory consumption and so on.

Comment: It tells you which node is executed when. When enabled in heavy compositing trees, you can see the nodes highlighted one after the other in the order of execution. The idea behind is to identify nodes that are slow to execute.

Comment: So, is it working only with heavy setups? Does anybody have a screenshot of nodes being highlighted by this option?

Comment: Weird. I remember this worked a while ago for me, but I haven't used it in quite some time. I'll keep investigating this. All resources so far, even in the manual and the tooltip, say the same: It highlights the node currently executed. But it doesn't show up for me atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Blender Bug Tracker](https://developer.blender.org/rB1f96dd2e0bb7440002b24c98e4c9d7daa44f2ebd):

> This feature was disabled in the code but not in the interface.